# Collision probability with random number plus timestamp as a username

Tags: probability

Say I need to generate a random username for an user. So I first set it as a random number generated using a function. In the next case I set the username to random number + timestamp. Which case has more probability of a collision ? Is it even decidable ?

Edit
Please note that I am not generating usernames to be used by people. Its just a placeholder.

And most importantly I'm not appending the timestamp. I'm rather performing an addition.

To further elaborate, take the random number to be 105 and the timestamp to be 106. So the username will be 211. Later the timestamp will be a bigger number but there is still a probability that during the timestamp 201 the generated random number might be 10, making it 211 again.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, the more characters you have, the less likely you are to have a collision. Chance of collision will be 1/(#OfcharsInUsername ^ #ofpossiblecharacters supported). For example, a 5 character password using only the lowercase alphabet will have a 1/(5^26) chance of a collision. Since you are appending a timestamp to the username it will be hard to have a collision occur. I see 3 potential issues however. The first is that you need to make sure you use a time fed random function, or you will have the same username multiple times. The second is that if you use a time fed random number generator than if you generate two usernames at the same time they will be exactly the same (even if you append the time to the end). The last one is that if you append the timestamp to the end of the username its going to be quite annoying for people entering the username, as timestamps have a bunch of colons and other garbage associated with them. I would prompt you to look for a different solution, producing a mix of letters and numbers. A different solution might be to grab a set amount of random numbers and use their ascii values to concatenate a username. Going from 21 to 126 would give you all of the lower and upper case letters, along with the numbers and some symbols. In addition this would make it very difficult to have collision because it wouldn't execute perfectly in time with another password. Likelyhood of collision would be 1/(n^105) where n is the number of characters.

Comment: Thanks Bob. But I am not appending the timestamp. I'm performing an addition with the timestamp. So it won't necessarily make the number of characters larger.

Comment: Even with that being the case, you will still have the issue of both time fed and normal random number generators producing collisions.